# Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, implicit-conversion

```
//
//  ParkMeterViewController.h

@interface ParkMeterViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>

{
    BOOL meterPickerIsDisplayed;
    BOOL reminderPickerIsDisplayed;
}
```

**and then in the .m file**

```
//
//  ParkMeterViewController.m

- (void)extendRetractPicker:(UIDatePicker *)picker
                   andLabel:(UILabel*)label
                withPickerY:(int)pickerY
                  andLabelY:(int)labelY
             withDisplayVar:(id)isDisplayed
              andDisplaySet:(BOOL)status    {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         picker.center = CGPointMake(picker.frame.origin.x + (picker.frame.size.width/2), pickerY);
                         label.center = CGPointMake(label.frame.origin.x + (label.frame.size.width/2), labelY);
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    isDisplayed = status;
}




//call for the method
 if (reminderPickerIsDisplayed == NO) {

    [self extendRetractPicker:reminderTimePicker andLabel:closeReminderLabel withPickerY:435 andLabelY:314 withDisplayVar:reminderPickerIsDisplayed andDisplaySet:YES];

}
```

Essentially I'm trying to get the isDisplayed variable in the method declaration to be the BOOL variable name that needs to be changed and then status as the new status for that BOOL.

Comment: isDisplayed is not reminderPickerIsDisplayed

Comment: "(id)isDisplayed andDisplaySet:(BOOL)status". You are assigning a BOOL to an id, just as the error message says.

Comment: im trying to get the method variable isDisplayed to point to one of the variable in the .h so when i set the isDisplayed in the method is will set that. The same way you can pass in a UIButton reference and do work to it in the method it effects the instance of it.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  What are you passing as the isDisplayed argument?

Comment: Logan-im trying to get the method variable isDisplayed to point to one of the variable in the .h so when i set the isDisplayed in the method is will set that. The same way you can pass in a UIButton reference and do work to it in the method it effects the instance of it

Comment: Why do you need it to point to the variable in the .h? You can just access the variable directly.

Comment: i have several different BOOLS that i use determine things current state. i need to pass the reference to the correct BOOL in so that i can change its state

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change it to a BOOL as suggested by @AminoAcids ? Why does it need to be an object (id)?

Comment: When i was running it as a BOOL i got no errors but the isDisplayed does not change the BOOL that is in the .h

Comment: The code that I had in my project was exactly what you suggested however when isDisplayed is changed within the method the BOOL that was sent into does not.

Comment: What you are doing seems screwy, but I get the feeling you're going to persist with it, so maybe changing it to a pointer to a BOOL in the method declaration and then assigning to the dereferenced bool within the method will do what you want. When you call the method you of course need to pass the address of the variable as the parameter not the variable itself.

Comment: im new to OBJ-C so if what im doing is not right im more than willing to listen and change it if necessary. I'm just trying to learn what im doing, and how to do it.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a side-effect to change the value of a variable that is passed in to the method.  You can do this if you pass the reference to the variable and then de-reference the pointer, but don't.  You could just change the method signature to `(BOOL)` instead of `(void)` and return status, but then you are just returning a value that is passed to your method without modifying it, so it could be a straight assignment in the invoking code.  Perhaps if you show how you are calling this method it would help

Comment: would it be better to send in an INT and then just use an if() statement to determine which variable to assign the status to?

Comment: That would be marginally better but not best. But its not really possible to say what is best without knowing the full bigger picture of exactly what you want to do and why. Other solutions might be (I say might be as I don't really know what you want to do) a delegate, or a block but if your're new maybe getting a bit to far ahead.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean when you say reference the variable and then dereference the pointer

Comment: You'll need to read a chapter of a C or C++ book on variables versus address of variables and passing parameters by value versus passing by reference. :(BOOL*)isDisplayed is a parameter type of pointer to BOOL.  Assign to it by *isDisplayed = status. When you call the method put & in front of the variable to pass its address.

Comment: You can pass the address of the variable with & and the in your method it will be received as a `BOOL *`, not a `BOOL` - so what you have done is pass the address in memory of the variable, so when you update the value you are affecting the original variable, not a local copy of the value.  But as I said, don't.  There are some cases where a side-effect is acceptable but this is unlikely to be one of those.

Comment: @Aminoacids- I have 2 DatePickers that im trying to animate. im trying to send in the BOOL variable(meterPickerIsDisplayed) and then the status would be its new status. so that when the method exits the variable meterPickerIsDisplayed has been changed to the new status that was sent in

Comment: Sorry MKD_FS its late here and my head is  too tired to digest your problem, maybe tomorrow if its still outstanding.

Comment: Thanks for all of the Help, its appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be simply done by changing the method invocation - For example:

```
if (reminderPickerIsDisplayed == NO) {

    [self extendRetractPicker:reminderTimePicker andLabel:closeReminderLabel withPickerY:435 andLabelY:314];
    reminderPickerIsDisplayed=YES;

}
```

Or you could change the `extendRetractPicker` method to

```
- (BOOL)extendRetractPicker:(UIDatePicker *)picker
                   andLabel:(UILabel*)label
                withPickerY:(int)pickerY
                  andLabelY:(int)labelY
             isDisplayed:(BOOL)isDisplayed    {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         picker.center = CGPointMake(picker.frame.origin.x + (picker.frame.size.width/2), pickerY);
                         label.center = CGPointMake(label.frame.origin.x + (label.frame.size.width/2), labelY);
                     }
                     completion:nil];

   return !isDisplayed;
}
```

and then your invocation would simply be

```
reminderPickerIsDisplayed = [self extendRetractPicker:reminderTimePicker andLabel:closeReminderLabel withPickerY:435 andLabelY:314 isDisplayed:reminderPickerIsDisplayed];
```

Comment: Yes, in both cases that works and is exactly what i was looking for. I guess i was over thinking what i was trying to do. Thank you greatly!

Comment: The top half works, just taking out the Bool from the method and changing it on the next line. I feel dumb for not seeing something that simple. The bottom half however still gives me the ARC error because im still sending a BOOL variable in to a method asking for an ID

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake - I didn't change the method signature when I copied/pasted.  I have fixed it

Comment: Yes that Works, Thank you Tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

This just demonstrates how important it is to start all your instance variable with an underscore character, as everybody with a bit of Objective-C experience would tell you. You obviously were quite convinced that you assigned the BOOL parameter "status" to the BOOL instance variable "meterPickerIsDisplayed" or "reminderPickerIsDisplayed" (I don't know which one), so convinced actually that you attributed the compiler error message to some weirdness going on that you couldn't understand, while in reality you tried to assign the BOOL parameter "status" to the id parameter "isDisplayed". Which even if it had been legal wouldn't have made any sense.

It also shows how important it is to use sensible variable names. Why "withDisplayVar:(id)isDisplayed"? isDisplayed is how you would name a BOOL variable. It should have been called "idToDisplay" or something similar. Then if you had tried to assign

```
idToDisplay = status;
```

you'd have figured out that this looks wrong.

Comment: I was trying to pass the isDisplayed variable as a pointer the the variable that i wanted to change based on what i passed in.

Comment: Thanks for the unnecessary non-constructive criticism and degrading tone.